# connecting to sql server and run script

Tags: sql, sql-server, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i have ec2 linux box , Jenkins installed . from Jenkins i want to connect the sql server , Connect to the database and run script to create schema any one has idea.

i am trying with shell script as passing db details as parameters , but didn't work .

Comment: can you specify what error your getting, connection refused,timeout etc..

Comment: Adding more details will help. Please add some code snippet and also the errors you encountered.

Comment: Sunil, is that you?

Comment: I am getting connection refused error , not able to integrate jenkins with microsoft sql server .

Comment: Any plugin required to install i tried with database plugin , but i didn't get any info to configure , jenkins instance( aws ec2 unix ) . Microsoft sql server , jenkins are in same vpn . wat else i have to check or configure to integrate microsoft sql server with jenkins and run the script (database script) from jenkins on microsoft sql server